# Filtering based on properties of objects within array using $filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

Assuming the following data:

```
var roster = [
    {
        id: 1,
        attended: true,
        person: {printName: 'Larry'}},
    {
        id: 2,
        attended: false,
        person: {printName: 'Curly'}},
    {
        id: 3,
        attended: true,
        person: {printName: 'Moe'}}];
```

I am trying to find the count of objects in the array where attended is true. I have tried the following:

**rosters.html:**

```
{{ (roster | filter:{attended:true} ).length }}
```

**rosters-controller.js:**

```
checkedInCount: function() {
    return $filter('filter')($scope.roster, attended.true).length;
}
```

The html filter works as expected, returning 2 in this instance. However, the function version encounters the error `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: attended`. I assume that there is something trivial that I've missed in the function, but I am not sure what it is.

Comment: Please compare attentively both of your versions. If you can't find what's going on, have a look at [the expected type](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) of the arguments.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I had skimmed that page, but I completely misunderstood how to build the `expression` argument. After seeing @tasseKATT's answer, it totally makes sense now.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain? My question turned out to have a simple answer, but I didn't think it was poor according to [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an object as the expression:

```
return $filter('filter')($scope.roster, { attended: true }).length;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm kicking myself for not seeing that before.